# Java: Export new Graphics object based off another Graphics object as PNG

Tags: java, swing, graphics, save, bufferedimage

I a stuck on trying to export an image of a graphics object.

This is what the method looks like:

```
    private BufferedImage paintImage;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);

    paintImage = new BufferedImage(500, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D statsExGraphics = paintImage.createGraphics();
    imageText.paint(statsExGraphics);

    try{
        ImageIO.write(paintImage, "PNG", new File("src/statsexport2.png"));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    map.paint(g);
    imageText.paint(g);

    switch (backgroundState) {
        case 1: 
            grid.paintItems(g);
            penguin.paint(g);
            purpleBear.paint(g);
            blueBear.paint(g);
            break;
        case 2: 
            EndgameGraphics done = new EndgameGraphics(endCondition);
            done.run();
            break;
        default: System.out.println("Error invalid background");
    }
}
```

I would have casted the g object onto the Graphics2D object, but then the BufferedImage object would not be connected to the graphics..

I need to export the object altogether so I can redisplay it onto a panel at the end of the game. The done (EndgameGraphics object) is code that produces a new JFrame with a background image and a button, and I need to reinsert the imageText graphics object into this new JFrame. In EndgameGraphics I dispose of the JFrame that contains all the stuff being painted originally in the method above and instantiates a new JFrame.

I am thinking the line,

```
imageText.paint(statsExGraphics);
```

is not a statement that executed the logic I am looking for, I am not sure where to go from here.

The current code is producing a blank image. Is there a method of Graphics2D that takes an argument of Graphics and paints it onto the Graphics2D object?

Maybe there is another way in which I can copy this graphics object and re-create it in EndgameGraphics to be added to the new JFrame?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming `imageText` is some kind of component, if so, you should be using `print` or `printAll` not `paint` - also, never reference `src`, it won't exist once the app is exported

Comment: Don't perform IO in paint methods, this will severely reduce the perform of your App

Comment: Based on the limited information I have, I would recommend, instead of using `paint` (you should be using `paintComponent`, but I'll leave that for now) to paint the state, paint the state to a `BufferedImage` during the update phase of your game loop, use this within your paint methods instead

Comment: How would one go about painting the state to a BufferedImage? I was under the impression that "imageText.paint(statsExGraphics);" was doing this?

Comment: Well, basically, instead of using `paint`, you would, in your main loop, create a `BufferedImage` and use it's `Graphics` context to render the current state, you would then, in the `paint` method, paint this image.  This means you already have the image you want to do want you with - this is a primitive example of double buffering

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your suggestions